# FindFit problem

Tags: fitting

This is my first question in this forum.
I have a relative humidity data as you can see in this excel-sheet:

[RH data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6kqelibjbpu1l4/RH.xlsx?dl=0)

I need to find the Di (drying diffusion coefficient) using FindFit, but the final fit is not very accurate as shown below. I will find something for Di but I want the tail of my graph to be fitted well too, as shown in the red marked area... Can anyone help me with this? I am sure I just need to adjust something, like matching with my data. I don't know how.
The first 2 columns in the excel file is what I am working on. Please ignore the other columns.

"t" is time, L, y, RHinitial, and RHbound also cannot be changed.

[image: My code]

Code:

```
RHdatafile = Import["RH.xlsx"];
RHdata = RHdatafile[[1, 3 ;; All, All]];
topRH = RHdata[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
midRH = RHdata[[All, 3 ;; 4]];
botRH = RHdata[[All, 5 ;; 6]];
RHinitial = 92.8;
RHbound = 70;
L = 0.102;
y = 0.038;
RHfittop = 
  FindFit[topRH, {RHinitial + 
     RHinitial Erfc[L/Sqrt[
       di t]] + (RHbound - 
        RHinitial) (Erfc[(L - 2 y)/(4 Sqrt[di t])] + 
        Erfc[(3 L + 2 y)/(4 Sqrt[di t])]), 
    0 < di < 0.00003}, {di}, t];

di = di /. RHfittop

Show[Plot[{RHinitial + 
    RHinitial Erfc[L/Sqrt[
      di t]] + (RHbound - 
       RHinitial) (Erfc[(L - 2 0.038)/(4 Sqrt[di t])] + 
       Erfc[(3 L + 2 0.038)/(4 Sqrt[di t])])}, {t, 0, 200}, 
  PlotRange -> {40, 100}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (d)", "RH(%)"}], 
 ListPlot[topRH, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (d)", "RH(%)"}]]
```

Comment: Please post code, rather than an image of code.

Comment: People here generally like to copy-paste a code so they can play with it, so don't post an image of a code. You can format the code with the `{}` button; go to help by clicking the `?` button for additional details.

Comment: Without going too much in details of your code I would expect that most probable, the model should be improved.

Comment: with such a single parameter fit you can manually adjust the parameter and look for a fit ( use `Manipulate` ) and sometimes do better than `FindFit` or at least find a good initial guess for `FindFit`.   Otherwise I think asking for a better model is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: "t" is time, L, y, RHinitial, and RHbound also cannot be changed.

Comment: To echo what @AlexeiBoulbitch and george2079 stated:  You need a better model.  With just one free parameter, that curve just won't bend the the way you want to fit the data.  Just another case of data getting in the way of theory.

Comment: Well, I guess you guys are all right. It seems my RHbound has not been measured accurately. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the one-parameter, `di`, model fitted to the data is not good enough to describe the data adequately. Also, it was stated by the OP that one parameter, `RHbound`, might not had been measured correctly. So, let's fit a two-parameter model:

```
RHfittop = 
 FindFit[topRH, {RHinitial + 
    RHinitial Erfc[
      L/Sqrt[di t]] + (RHbound - 
       RHinitial) (Erfc[(L - 2 y)/(4 Sqrt[di t])] + 
       Erfc[(3 L + 2 y)/(4 Sqrt[di t])]), 0 < di < 0.00003}, {di, 
   RHbound}, t]

{di, RHbound} = {di, RHbound} /. RHfittop
```

> {0.0000109214, 68.0971}

Both these parameters don't differ much from `RHbound = 70`, originally set by the OP, and `di = 0.0000154358`:

```
plot1 = Plot[{RHinitial + 
    RHinitial Erfc[
      L/Sqrt[di t]] + (RHbound - 
       RHinitial) (Erfc[(L - 2 0.038)/(4 Sqrt[di t])] + 
       Erfc[(3 L + 2 0.038)/(4 Sqrt[di t])])}, {t, 0, 200}, 
  PlotRange -> {40, 100}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (d)", "RH(%)"}];

plot2 = ListPlot[topRH, PlotRange -> {All, {40, 100}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (d)", "RH(%)"}]

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Visually, this result is much better than the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot corey979. You are very right about the RHbound being around 68%. In fact I tried 68% and I found a much better fit as well. This means that I should report my measured RHbound as 70+/-2%. You had a very smart answer.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, even if I let all of the parameters float I can't fit the data with the model supplied by the OP.

The shape of the data looks like a exponential decline superimposed on a line.

```
RHfittop = 
 FindFit[topRH, a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int,
  {{a, 15}, {b, 0.1}, {sl, -0.03}, {int, 70}}, t]

(* {a -> 15.3197, b -> 0.092728, sl -> -0.0333243, int -> 77.4412} *)

RHfitmid = 
 FindFit[midRH, a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int,
 {{a, 15}, {b, 0.1}, {sl, -0.03}, {int, 70}}, t]

(* {a -> 15.4196, b -> 0.0586449, sl -> -0.0435704, int -> 81.756} *)

RHfitbot = 
 FindFit[botRH, a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int,
 {{a, 15}, {b, 0.1}, {sl, -0.03}, {int, 70}}, t]

(* {a -> 17.7906, b -> 0.0404087, sl -> -0.0406912, int -> 82.0845} *)
```

Now define three functions based upon the fits

```
top[t_] := Evaluate[a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int /. RHfittop]

mid[t_] := Evaluate[a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int /. RHfitmid]

bot[t_] := Evaluate[a Exp[-b t] + sl t + int /. RHfitbot]
```

Plot the data versus the fits

Show[

```
 Plot[
  {top[t], mid[t], bot[t]},
  {t, 0, 200},
  PlotRange -> {70, 95},
  (*PlotStyle\[Rule]Black,*)
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (d)", "RH(%)"}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {topRH, midRH, botRH},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> Black
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Jack LaVigne for your time. I knew the RH function from the beginning but I wanted to find "di" as I mentioned in my question using that expression I have used in Findfit. corey979 nailed it.